# php select only one image for each item

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables ('items' and 'images') and would like to get a list of items with only one image for each item.

Let's say `item_id` is 1, and this item has 5 records at the `images` table, with my code item 1 will show 5 times at the while loop as it has 5 images, but this is not what i'm after.

I need the item to show only once with one image only.

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM items, images 
  WHERE item_banner = 'Yes' 
    AND item_publish = 'Yes' 
    AND image_type = 'img' 
    AND item_id = image_item_id  
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: And what  image to show? If you have 5 for each item then which one to choose?

Comment: the very first image at the images table which has image_item_id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the image by the lowest image_id for the specific item, assuming `images` has an id column.

I am curious about the condition `image_type = 'img'` though. Do you have images with a different type than `img`? :)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  items i
  LEFT JOIN images
    ON image_item_id = item_id -- Not strictly needed, I guess
    AND image_type = 'img'
    AND image_id = (
      SELECT MIN(image_id) 
      FROM images 
      WHERE image_item_id = item_id)
WHERE item_banner = 'Yes' 
    AND item_publish = 'Yes' 
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks a lot, about your curious  question :), at the same table there is also image_type 'vid' which is you tube video links for the same item, just didn't want to create a new table for videos , but smart question , thanks again for helping me at this query :)

Answer (score 0):

with my case this code without repeat any column and very simple
i have one table for items info and one for item images

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW items_page AS
select i.item_name,i.price,i.unit,
(select min(item_images.item_id)  from item_images where item_images.item_id=i.case_id order by item_images.item_id asc)as item_id ,(select image_url from item_images where item_images.item_id=i.case_id order by item_images.item_id limit 1)as imageurl  
from item i
```